# How to pass in props to Link Router?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Hello I want to pass in props to another component through Link Router

I am using Class Component

```
  constructor(props: IBanner) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      jobCategories: [],
      jobKeyword: "",
      jobLocation: "",
   };


  }
```

and here is my
Link Router

```
 <Link {{
                pathname: '/search-results',
                state: {
                  jobKeyword: this.state.jobKeyword, jobLocation: this.state.jobLocation
                  }
                  }}>
                <li className="ktp-banner-submit">
                  {" "}
                  <input type="submit" value="" />{" "}
                  <i className="ktp-icon ktp-search"></i>{" "}
                </li>
                </Link>
```

However I am getting an error of  Property 'to' is missing in type '{ children: Element; pathname: string; state: { jobKeyword: string; jobLocation: string; }; }' but required in type 'LinkProps'

What error is this and what can i do to mitigate this/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `to` attribute. Try this:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: '/search-results',
    state: {
      jobKeyword: this.state.jobKeyword, jobLocation: this.state.jobLocation
    }
  }}
/>
```

You cannot do something like this in React:

```
<Component {obj} />
```

You need to assign that object to an attribute:

```
<Component p={obj} />
```

Or you can destruct the object(attributes):

```
<Component ...{{name:'foo', lastName: 'bar'}} />
```

Which translates to:

```
<Component name='foo' lastName='bar' />
```